# How to increment the search count in php/mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, count, increment

I have a table consists of several fields (`id`, `firstname`, `surname`, `username`, `search_count`)

I've build a small search engine that search my table to find any match exists either in the `firstname` or in the `surname` and I am getting the results with no problems.

Now, what I am trying to do is to increment the `search_count` field by 1 every time there is a match!

For example let's say we have the following table `users`:

```
id | firstname | surname  | username | search_count 
1  | John      | Mike     | un1      | 0
2  | John      | Jeff     | un2      | 0
3  | Dale      | John     | un3      | 0
4  | Mike      | Gorge    | un4      | 0
```

and let's say we are searching for `Jeff` as a keyword

so, the query will return 1 record

what I want to do is to increment the `search_count` by `1` for match record

so the results will be something like as:

```
id | firstname | surname  | username | search_count 
2  | John      | Jeff     | un2      | `1`
```

and if we make a new search (e.g. `John`) the results should be something like:

```
id | firstname | surname  | username | search_count 
1  | John      | Mike     | un1      | 1
2  | John      | Jeff     | un2      | 2
3  | Dale      | John     | un3      | 1
```

I've tried several approach but with no luck.. So I appreciate any hints and help

here is my code...

```
<?php
// open the HTML page
include 'html_open.php';
// require the db connection
require '/inc/db.inc.php';
// require the error messages
require '/inc/echo.inc.php';



    if (isset($_GET['keyword'])) {
        $keyword = $_GET['keyword'];
        if (!empty($keyword)) {
            // build our search query
            $search_query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `firstname` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($keyword)."' OR `surname` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($keyword)."' ORDER BY `search_count` DESC";
            // run the search query
            $search_query_run = mysql_query($search_query);
            // search results
            $search_results_num = mysql_num_rows($search_query_run);
            // check query return results
            if ($search_results_num>0) {        
                echo 'Search engine returns <strong>[ '.$search_results_num.' ]</strong> result(s) for <strong>[ '.$keyword.' ]</strong>:<br>';
                // retrieving the information found
                echo '<ol>';
                while ($search_result_information = mysql_fetch_assoc($search_query_run)) {
                    //$current_search_count = ;
                    echo '<li>'.$search_result_information['username'].'.  This user has been searched: '.$search_result_information['search_count'].' times before.</li>';
                }
                echo '</ol><hr>';
                include 'search_form.php';
            } else {
                echo '<hr>Search engine returns no result for <strong>[ '.$keyword.' ]</strong>, please try another keyword.<hr>'; // hint: no result found
                include 'search_form.php';
            }               
        } else {
            echo $err20_002; // hint: must insert input
            include 'search_form.php';
        }
    } else {
            echo $err20_001; // hint: form has not been submitted
            include 'search_form.php';
    }
// close the HTML page  
include 'html_close.php';   
?>
```

P.S. I am new to PHP / MySQL and this is my first code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...
while ($search_result_information = mysql_fetch_assoc($search_query_run)) {
    # add this following line
    mysql_query('UPDATE `users` SET search_count=search_count+1 WHERE id='.$search_result_information['id']);
    # Edit. Change result to show new number
    $search_result_information['search_count']++; # this adds 1 to the value (does not affect stored data in database)
    echo '<li>'.$search_result_information['username'].'.  This user has been searched: '.$search_result_information['search_count'].' times before.</li>';
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks that work, but is there a way to increment the counter before displaying the echo?

Comment: Not without making more DB requests than necessary, the most simple and logical answer is to +1 to that value before outputting. Will edit my asnwer.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you need to fetch the found values and perform an update statement adding +1 to the `search_count` column

```
$search_query = "SELECT id, firstname, surname, username, search_count FROM `users` WHERE `firstname` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($keyword)."' OR `surname` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($keyword)."' ORDER BY `search_count` DESC";
$search_query_run = mysql_query($search_query);
        // search results
        $search_results_num = mysql_num_rows($search_query_run);
        // check query return results
        if ($search_results_num>0) {        
            echo 'Search engine returns <strong>[ '.$search_results_num.' ]</strong> result(s) for <strong>[ '.$keyword.' ]</strong>:<br>';
            // retrieving the information found
            echo '<ol>';
            while ($search_result_information = mysql_fetch_assoc($search_query_run)) {
                //$current_search_count = ;
                $update_search = "UPDATE users SET search_count = search_count + 1 WHERE id = {$search_result_information['id']}"; // so every `id` will increment its search_count with 1. You will need to select the rows once again, to take this count, or to manually increment in PHP
                mysql_query($update_search);
                echo '<li>'.$search_result_information['username'].'.  This user has been searched: '.$search_result_information['search_count'].' times before.</li>';
```

P.S.: Using mysql_* lib is strongly NOT recommended. As you can see from the red box in the official  documentation http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php you should choose one of the current actually supported APIs

Comment: Thanks for the P.S., I know that but I thought I would first get my code working with the mysql_* since I find it much easy to understand then update it to the mysqli_*

Comment: yes, it is working fine,, thanks but is there a way that we can update the search count before echoing the result?

Comment: If you  want to return the new count, you can echo just +1 to each result, or in your select statement to add +1 to the column result. This is the shortest I can get in mind. The longer is to make a select, iterate through the rows and update. Then make another select, and then echo.